# Razor can not understand ViewBag inside Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using mvc 5, Using this code I don´t get ViewBag.Arrival in my controller i get it every time with Null what is the problem

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Parameters.Checkin, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new {     @class = "calendarr font", @id = "Arrival",  @name = "Arrival", @value = (String)ViewBag.Arrival, @readonly = "readonly", @onchange = "changedDate();" })
```

this is my Home controller :

```
   if (ViewBag.Arrival == true)
    {
        mySessionObject.Parameters.Checkin = ViewBag.Arrival;
        mySessionObject.Parameters.Checkout = ViewBag.Departure;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you fill ViewBag.Arrival?

Comment: i want to fill it from model at first time page load then take last changed value and put it again in the second load

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to send back data from view to `action` with `viewbag` it wont work because it only does one way trip so you should get the value in `Model.Parameters.Checkin` and change `@value` to `@Value` use capital `V` because razor wont recognize small `v` `@value`

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Parameters.Checkin, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new {@class = "calendarr font", @id = "Arrival",  @name = "Arrival", @Value = (String)ViewBag.Arrival, @readonly = "readonly", @onchange = "changedDate();" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fill `ViewBag` inside `controller` and use them in `Views`.

If you use `ViewBag.Arrival` in your `Index` view you should fill it inside `Index` action of `Home` controller.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    ViewBag.Arrival = true;
}
```

Now `ViewBag.Arrival` value is `true` if you use it inside `Index` view.
Notice that `ViewBag` variables keep their value just for their own views. This means if you fill `ViewBag.Arrival` in `Index` it will be null in `ContactUs` View.